# Is it possible to expand an input box purely with HTMX?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, htmx

I want to build an input box where if the text reached to the bottom of the input box, it automatically increases the input box's height to fit the text. Is that possible by using purely HTMX?

or is it only possible with javascript? because i dont know

Comment: I was wondering if i can do it with HTMX or not. If not then I will use javascript

Comment: Ahh, OK - a simple misunderstanding on my part

Comment: you could do it with HTMX, where the server returns a larger textarea depending on the length of its content, but it wouldn't be efficient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per my knowledge this type functionality generally required JavaScript to constantly monitor the textarea size and change the size accordingly.
you can add javascript on the textarea like this:

```
<body>
<textarea id="input-box" rows="1" oninput="autoResize(this)"></textarea>
<script>
function autoResize(textarea) {
textarea.style.height = "auto";
textarea.style.height = (textarea.scrollHeight) + "px";
}
</script>
</body>
```

hope this will help you.